# how to get rid of the ranking column in jabref?

Tags: jabref

Space is always limited and I found that I do not use the `ranking` column in the Jabref entry table. When I go to `Options` -> `Preferences` -> `Entry table columns` and adjust the `Entry table columns` table and delete `rankings` and adjuste the column width I see that the column widths are changed, but the `rankings` column remains. If I add a `rankings` column with a very small width, I get the `rankings` column twice, both perhaps 80 character wide.

Is there a way to remove the `rankings` column?

Why is `rankings` treated in a special way?

Comment: Which JabRef version are you using?

Comment: sorry for not including - this came with ubuntu. JabRef 3.8.2
linux 5.8.0-1007-raspi aarch64 
Java 11.0.9.1  - would  new version be better?

Comment: In newer jabref versions(e.g. 5.1) there is a switch Show Special fields in the entry table preferences. That allows you to hide those fields like ranking. Before upgrading its recommended to make a backup of your library